# SQL 2017 : Need to convert json with column name as a value and actual value is value of another one

Tags: sql-server-2017

HI I need to convert Json stored in 1 of the columns in a table to flat tables with specific fields.
Note : Column names are not always ""Request type,Country...".Columsn are dynamic and should be picked from value in "Name"

Below is the json from 1 row.

```
{"JobID":1,"ItemID":1,"Attributes":[{"ID":1,"Name":"Request Type","Value":"1","ValueString":"Buy"},{"ID":3,"Name":"Country","Value":"2","ValueString":"USA"},{"ID":5,"Name":"Number","Value":"1","ValueString":"1"}]}
```

[I need this to be converted as in attached format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKcvC.jpg)

Comment: Cannot see any image ...

Comment: Can you please check now

Comment: Still no image, unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, scrap that - I can see the attached image now, sorry about that.

Comment: OK, I saw the image, but it does not help me, unfortunately. Your JSON does not add up with what the image shows. Also, what are the "*" in your JSON? I am not trying to be funny, but if you want help, please give us as a full example as possible.

Comment: I tried to bold the text so that u know the column name and values.When i clicked on bold while adding question stack overflow added with ** and not sure why it didn't convert to bold while showing in UI.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter you should check [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server):

```
DECLARE @j NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"JobID":1,"ItemID":1,"Attributes":[{"ID":1,"Name":"Request Type","Value":"1","ValueString":"Buy"},{"ID":3,"Name":"Country","Value":"2","ValueString":"USA"},{"ID":5,"Name":"Number","Value":"1","ValueString":"1"}]}'
```

And query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@j)
WITH (JobID INT '$.JobID',
      ItemId INT '$.ItemID',
      [Request_Type] NVARCHAR(100) '$.Attributes[0].ValueString',
      Country NVARCHAR(100) '$.Attributes[1].ValueString',
      [Number] NVARCHAR(100) '$.Attributes[2].ValueString'
      );
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c040181220f4c0e1796669cb9a622511)**

Comment: I am sorry i should have mentioned. Column name is dynamic.Its not always "request type,country.."We need to pick column name from value of "Name" key